# Make Debian Pause before rebooting

Tags: linux, debian, reboot

I need my linux machine to reboot, but I need it to pause before booting back up. I am doing this remotely though ssh. (1 to 5mins) Is this possible?

Comment: So you want it to shutdown immediately, but not come back up for some amount of time, is that right?  You don't want to have it start to shutdown in some time, the delay should happen after the shutdown?

Comment: @EricRenouf Yes i want it to shutdown wait then come back up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed -e 's/^GRUB_TIMEOUT.*/GRUB_TIMEOUT=300/' -i /etc/default/grub
update-grub
reboot
```

Comment: so if i am understanding this correctly this will shutdown my computer wait 5mins and then boot it back up?

Comment: no. it only makes 5 minutes delay in grub. You have to reboot regurarly. (but i can expand my answer with a `reboot`, if you never heard of this command before)

Comment: yes please add details to the answer, i am testing it now

Comment: For some reason i can't find '/etc/default/grub' file. the directory '/etc/default' is there but grub isn't. I'm running raspbian if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options I can think of:

- Modify the time that Grub waits for a response before rebooting.  This is normally set to a few seconds.  The way this is handled depends on you Grub version as they are changing the way startup works.
- Delay the final shutdown. This is one of the options NUT uses to ensure the server reboots if the UPS does not cycle the power after a temporary failure.  This is done by adding a sleep as the last step before triggering a reboot.  The process used to shutdown the server may be one of two or three options currently being used.